# Can firebase process the data and push the result to mobile devices instead of just push the original?

Tags: firebase

Firebase can synchronize data among different mobile devices for real time application. Can I use firebase to perform any server side operations on those data and only push the result of those operations to interested devices, instead of raw data?

Like when a number on a mobile device is changed from 10 to 100, the server simply pushes a flag indicates larger, instead of pushing the new number, 100, to other devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase by itself does not provide you with a way to run your data manipulation code on their servers.

In the simplest case you can simply let the clients calculate those derived values, using a `transaction` in case there is a cross-client impact (as your example suggests).

You can also set up your own server that monitors your Firebase data (possibly through the same API you use for your clients), calculates those derived values and writes them back into Firebase. The actual mobile devices would then just be monitoring the derived values. This server should then be running under an elevated/trusted account, either a well-known name or by using the secret that you can find in your Firebase dashboard/forge.

You could even do the same as a client. So just have a web page that you run on a machine that you control and others can't access. But you're probably better off setting up a separate (e.g. node.js) server for this.

The most important thing to realize is that you don't need a real server at a hosting/data center to accomplish your needs. Firebase is firewall-friendly, unlike with many other services you don't need to provide a publicly reachable postback URL that they will call you on. So you can just run the "server" part of your application at home (depending on the reliability of your machine, internet connection and the up-to-date requirements of the derived data for your application).